# How do I clear a float only on mobile? And why is my media query for mobile affected when I remove the media query for tablets?

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to make a simple HTML/CSS site from scratch for the first time and I'm trying to adjust it for cell phones and tablets.

But the main content is displaying beside the navigation bars when displayed on a phone set to the horizontal position. I don't know how to clear the float in a media query.

Also, when I delete the tablet media query from my CSS... it affects the cell phone media query. Why is that?

```css
body {
  background-color: #EBF0DF;
  color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Papyrus, serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #A8BF78;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(../site_assets/logo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 8%;
  background-size: 145px;
  margin-left: 110px;
  margin-right: 110px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 400%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
}

header, nav, main, footer {
  display: block;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 4px outset #CEDAB3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #84A540;
  font-family: Verdana;
  padding: 5px;
}

nav a:link {
  color: #84A540;
}

nav a:visited {
  color: #A8BF78;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #CEDBB3;
}

footer {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #CEDBB3;
}

#portlandimage {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  min-width: 1200px;
  max-width: 1480px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: none;
  }

  h1 {
    margin: 0;
  }

  nav {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }

  nav a {
    padding: 1em;
  }

  main {
    padding: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    font-size: 90%;
  }

  footer {
    margin: 0;
  }

  #wrapper {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}

@media only all and (max-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background-image: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }

  nav {
    padding: 0;
  }

  nav a {
    float: left;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 75%;
    min-width: 6em;
    margin-left: 0.8em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
  }

  main {
    padding-top: 0.1em;
    padding-right: 0.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    padding-left: 0.4em;
  }

  footer {
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    font-style: normal;
  }

  #portlandimage {
    display: none;
  }

  #wrapper {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Portland Historical Tours</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
      <link href="styles/historical_tours_styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body id="wrapper">
      <header>
        <h1>Portland Historical Tours</h1>
      </header>
      <nav>
        <a href="project/template.html">Home</a> &nbsp;
        <a href="project/tours.html">Tours</a> &nbsp;
        <a href="project/about.html">About Us</a> &nbsp;
        <a href="project/contact.html">Contact</a>
      </nav>
      <main>
        <img alt="Portland, Oregon" height="460" id="portlandimage"
            src="site_assets/portland_historical_tours.jpg" style="float: right;" width="620">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed suscipit
        purus risus, mattis efficitur augue suscipit ut. Etiam lobortis auctor
        felis, a dignissim erat iaculis eu. Praesent et elit eu lectus lacinia
        posuere id in nisl. Aenean faucibus, massa eget eleifend rutrum, lectus
        diam ullamcorper mauris, vitae semper ligula dui et mauris. Nullam
        vulputate sem tincidunt elementum molestie. Fusce dignissim tristique
        rutrum. Proin gravida mi quam. Nam non eros a mauris aliquam blandit sit
        amet sed magna. Fusce auctor leo diam, eu pellentesque orci auctor id.
        Mauris tempor nulla ligula, sed rutrum tortor dictum sed. Morbi mollis
        cursus ipsum eget mattis.</p>
        <h2>Dolor Sit Amet</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed suscipit
        purus risus, mattis efficitur augue suscipit ut. Etiam lobortis auctor
        felis, a dignissim erat iaculis eu. Praesent et elit eu lectus lacinia
        posuere id in nisl. Aenean faucibus, massa eget eleifend rutrum, lectus
        diam ullamcorper mauris, vitae semper ligula dui et mauris. Nullam
        vulputate sem tincidunt elementum molestie. Fusce dignissim tristique
        rutrum. Proin gravida mi quam. Nam non eros a mauris aliquam blandit sit
        amet sed magna. Fusce auctor leo diam, eu pellentesque orci auctor id.
        Mauris tempor nulla ligula, sed rutrum tortor dictum sed. Morbi mollis
        cursus ipsum eget mattis.</p>
      </main><br>
      <br>
      <footer>
        Copyright &copy; 2017 Portland Historical Tours<br>
        <a href="mailto:sales@portlandhistoricaltours.com">sales@portlandhistoricaltours.com</a>
      </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“I don't know how to clear the float in a media query”_ – same way as outside of any media query ...

Comment: because you're not setting a min.. you just have a max, which means all devices upto Xpx - set a min to better distinguish device types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in `media query` at screen resolution of `1024px`, the same way you used `media query` to hide `display for image div` in `small screen resolution`, using same way you can make such many changes in your `media query`. Use clear:both to align text properly after menu in tag main.

> clear - The clear property specifies on which sides of an element
>   floating elements are not allowed to float.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
body {margin: 0; padding: 0; background-image: none;}
h1 {margin: 0;}
nav {float: none; width: auto; padding: 0.5em;}
nav a {padding: 1em;}
main {padding: 1em; margin-left: 0; font-size: 90%; clear:both;}
footer {margin: 0;}
#wrapper {width: auto; min-width: 0; margin: 0; box-shadow: none;}
}
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e45xtekf/).